# Typescript autoinject in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am new to Typescript and Aurelia. 
I am try to make @autoinject decorator work in VS2015 ASP.NET MVC 6 project.

Here is my code

```
import {autoinject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

@autoinject()
export class App {
       http: HttpClient;
       constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
          this.http = httpClient;
       }

       activate() {
          this.http.get("/api/test/")...
       }
}
```

when I run this I get an error saying this.http is undefined.

I believe I need to add TypeScript's emitDecoratorMetadata flag but I don't know how.

I have tried adding tsconfig.json file to my project and set that flag in compiler options but then I get a bunch of errors (duplicate identifier).
How can I fix these errors. Do I need to add something to "files"? What exactly?

Here is my config.js file

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"
  },

  map: {
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.0.7",
    "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.0.0-beta.1",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.7.5",
     ....
  }
  });
```

Comment: please update the full error. mean while answered as per your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How does @autoInject() work?

> Before you need to aware of TypeScript's `emitDecoratorMetadata` flag causes the TypeScript compiler to polyfill the Metadata Reflection API and add a special decorator definition to the transpiled TypeScript code.
>
> Aurelia's @autoInject() decorator consumes the type metadata created by TypeScript's decorator and applies it to the class in the same way that the @inject(...) decorator does.

Try like below and you need to enable the new option in the `compilerOptions` of Type Script.

TS Configuration:

```
{
    "version": "1.5.1",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noLib": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Snippet Screenshot from Article:

[image]

Article about emitDecoratorMetadata:
http://blog.durandal.io/2015/05/06/getting-started-with-aurelia-and-typescript/
http://www.danyow.net/inversion-of-control-with-aurelia-part-2/

Available Type Script Options:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options

> You can do it with Gulp-Typescript as well with Gulp option

Options: https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#options
GitHub Issue Thread: https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/100

Gulp Code Snippet: 
    gulp.task('build-ts', [], function() {

```
  return gulp.src(paths.typescript)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.js'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts({
      declarationFiles: false,
      noExternalResolve: true,
      target: 'es5',
      module: 'commonjs',
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
      typescript: typescript
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});
```

Comment: You are talking about inject decorator. My question is about autoinject decorator. They are not the same

Comment: interesting. let me check that out

Comment: @autoinject decorator to your class and leave out the Types in the decorator call, but just use them on the constructor's signature.

Comment: @partyelite, you have to use autoject in constructor signature. Refer this note: 
autoinject decorator to your class and leave out the Types in the decorator call, but just use them on the constructor's signature. Hope your TypeScript >= 1.5 !

Comment: I did that, look at my code above. I dont have any types in autoinjector call and have types in constructor of the class. I am using TypeScript 1.7.5

Comment: Update the answer. take a look at it !

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried running Basic gulp task.              var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('wwwroot/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('built/local'));
}); but then I got 11185 semantic errors. Such as "wwwroot\jspm_package\npm\typescript@1.7.5\lib\lib.core.d.ts  error TS2300 Duplicate identifier ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99416/discussion-between-venkatraman-and-partyelite).

Answer (score 1):

### What exactly @autoinject & @inject contains ?

As per `dependency-injection` Library of the `aurelia` Framework.

```
    /**
    * Decorator: Directs the TypeScript transpiler to write-out type metadata for the decorated class.
    */
    export function autoinject(potentialTarget?: any): any {
      let deco = function(target) {
        target.inject = metadata.getOwn(metadata.paramTypes, target) || _emptyParameters;
      };

      return potentialTarget ? deco(potentialTarget) : deco;
    }

    /**
    * Decorator: Specifies the dependencies that should be injected by the DI Container into the decoratored class/function.
    */
    export function inject(...rest: any[]): any {
      return function(target, key, descriptor) {
        // if it's true then we injecting rest into function and not Class constructor
        if (descriptor) {
          const fn = descriptor.value;
          fn.inject = rest;
        } else {
          target.inject = rest;
        }
      };
    }
```

> Source URL: https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/blob/master/src/injection.js

Comment: @partyelite, Check this to understand about autoinject & inject